# Brackets in exponentiation

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, fake-proofs

$ (-1)^{3}=((-1)^2)^\frac {3}{2}=(1)^\frac {3}{2}=1$

See, I know it's wrong but don't know why . Which rule is disobeyed here? And which rule should be followed in these cases?

Comment: $(a^{p})^{q}=a^{pq}$ is not valid for negaitve $a$.

Comment: The punchline is that $a^{bc}$ is not necessarily equal to $(a^b)^c$ when non-positive real numbers are involved as the base, i.e. your first equals sign was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The exponent multiplication rule does not hold in the complex case. In general for a complex number $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and real numbers $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$(z^a)^b \ne z^{ab}$$

Of course you can find some special cases where it does hold, but generally it does not. [You can see some examples here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentLaws.html) and [a proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079710/law-of-exponent-for-complex-numbers).

Now while it doesn't *look* like you're dealing with complex numbers, implicitely you are, since

$$(-1)^{1/2} = \sqrt{-1} = i$$

So immediately whenever there are **negative values raised to a non-whole value**, the **complex exponentiation rules** apply.